# The problem 'state value is changed to undefined when Redux action is called'

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have problem with changing store's state.
I want to set loggedIn and storeNum in login.js but when I call 'changeLoggedIn(true)' and 'setStoreNum(1)', the previously called value is changed to undefined.

Please give me advise to set both value together without undefined.

Thank you.

[image]

**reducer.js**

```
import { CHANGE_LOGGED_IN, SET_STORE_NUM } from './actions';

const defaultState={
    loggedIn: false,
    storeNum: 0,
  }
const loggedInReducer = ( state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {

    case CHANGE_LOGGED_IN:
      return{
        loggedIn: action.loggedIn
      }

    case SET_STORE_NUM:
      return{
        storeNum: action.storeNum
      }
    default: return state;
  };
};

export default loggedInReducer;
```

**actions.js**

```
export const SET_STORE_NUM = 'SET_STORE_NUM'


export const changeLoggedIn = (loggedIn) => ({
  type: CHANGE_LOGGED_IN,
  loggedIn: loggedIn,
});

export const setStoreNum = (storeNum) => ({
  type: SET_STORE_NUM,
  storeNum: storeNum,
})
```

**login.js**

```
export default connect(
    state => ({
        loggedIn: state.loggedIn,
        storeNum: state.storeNum
    }),
    dispatch => ({
        changeLoggedIn: (loggedIn) => dispatch(changeLoggedIn(loggedIn)),
        setStoreNum: (storeNum) => dispatch(setStoreNum(storeNum))
    })
)(Login);
```

Comment: As the answer shows below, each reducer must return the **entire** new state, not just the single new value.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thank you so much. now it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because you are only returning `loggedIn` for the `CHANGE_LOGIN` action.

Return this:

```
const loggedInReducer = ( state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {

    case CHANGE_LOGGED_IN:
      return{
        ...state,
        loggedIn: action.loggedIn
      }

    case SET_STORE_NUM:
      return{
        ...state,
        storeNum: action.storeNum
      }
    default: return state;
  };
};
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. It is working! But I have one more question, I know the meaning of ... expression but it is not working with old ipod touch(<=ios 11)'s safari web. Do you know any solution?

Comment: Sure, how have you configured the app or if you can share a reproducible example it would be great?

Comment: Hope this link helps you: https://redux.js.org/recipes/using-object-spread-operator

Comment: Solved problem with 'Object.assign' instead of using '...state'. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome glad it helped :)

Comment: @HojoongKim If you still have problems, feel free to post a new question.